# How to avoid date overlaps in Django models?

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-models

I have a model:

```
class Dimension_Item(models.Model):
    uq_dimension_item_id = MyCharField(max_length=1024, primary_key=True)
    dimension_id = MyCharField(max_length=1024)
    dimension_item_id = MyCharField(max_length=100)
    name = MyCharField(max_length=255)
    description = MyCharField(max_length=512, null = True)
    start_date = models.DateField(default=date(1,1,1))
    end_date = models.DateField(default=date(9999,12,31))
```

function for adding information to the model:

```
def addRows(in_args):
    rq = in_args[0]
    pk_l=[]
    rows = rq['rows']
    if type(rows).__name__ == 'dict':
        dim = Dimension_Item(
                        name=rows['name'],
                        start_date=rows['start_date'],
                        end_date=rows['end_date']
        )
        dim.save()
        pk_l.append(dim.dimension_id)
    elif type(rows).__name__ == 'list':
        for i in rows:
            dim = Dimension_Item(
                        name=rows['name'],
                        start_date=rows['start_date'],
                        end_date=rows['end_date']
            )
            dim.save()
            pk_l.append(dim.dimension_id)
    else:
        pass
    return getRows(in_args, pk_l)
    # return "success add row"
clauses.addMethod(addRows)
```

and function for modifying the model items:

```
def modifyRows(in_args):
    pk_l=[]
    rq = in_args[0]
    rows = rq['rows']
    if type(rows).__name__ == 'dict':
        dim = Dimension_Item.objects.get(pk=rows['pk'])
        for attr in rows:
            if attr!='pk':
                try:
                    setattr(dim, attr, rows[attr])
                except KeyError:
                    pass
        dim.save()
        pk_l.append(dim.dimension_id)
    elif type(rows).__name__ == 'list':
        for i in rows:
            dim = Dimension_Item.objects.get(pk=i['pk'])
            for attr in i:
                if i!='pk':
                    try:
                        setattr(dim, attr, i[attr])
                    except KeyError:
                        pass
            dim.save()
            pk_l.append(dim.dimension_id)
    else:
        pass
    return getRows(in_args, pk_l)
    # return "success modify"
clauses.addMethod(modifyRows)
```

I should check if start_date and end_date fields don't overlap other records in the database.

For example, I enter: 2.02.1988-3.07.1989. And if I already have the record with 2.07.1989 - 3.08.1990, I have to throw an exception about date overlapping.

How better can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would override the `save()` method of your `Dimension_Item` model.

In your custom save() method you can implement your check for overlapping dates.  If everything is OK, create the object. If not, just return nothing (or raise and error.)

The Django documentation explains it really good: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#overriding-model-methods

Here is some (untested) code to get you started:

```
class Dimension_Item(models.Model):
    start_date = models.DateField(default=date(1,1,1))
    end_date = models.DateField(default=date(9999,12,31))

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # get number of items that have an overlapping start date
        dimension_items_overlapping_start = Dimension_Item.objects.filter(start_date__gte=self.start_date, start_date__lte=self.end_date).count()

        # get number of items that have an overlapping end date
        dimension_items_overlapping_end = Dimension_Item.objects.filter(end_date__gte=self.start_date, end_date__lte=self.end_date).count()

        overlapping_dimension_items_present = dimension_items_overlapping_start > 0 or dimension_items_overlapping_end > 0

        if overlapping_dimension_items_present:
            return 
        else:
            super(Dimension_Item, self).save(*args, **kwargs) # Call the "real" save() method.
```

Comment: Thank you, but I was more interested in searching for date set intersection. How would you recommend to implement it in Django?

Comment: I have added some sample code that should work. (although I did not test it)

Comment: This does not work with the case where range of `self` can fit in another existing object.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Dimension_Item(models.Model):
    start_date = models.DateField(default=date(1,1,1))
    end_date = models.DateField(default=date(9999,12,31))

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # check for items that have an overlapping start date
        dimension_items_overlapping_start = Dimension_Item.objects.filter(start_date__gte=self.start_date, start_date__lte=self.end_date).exists()

        # check for items that have an overlapping end date
        dimension_items_overlapping_end = Dimension_Item.objects.filter(end_date__gte=self.start_date, end_date__lte=self.end_date).exists()

        # check for items that envelope this item
        dimension_items_enveloping = Dimension_Item.objects.filter(start_date__lte=self.start_date, end_date__gte=self.end_date).exists()

        overlapping_dimension_items_present = dimension_items_overlapping_start or dimension_items_overlapping_end or dimenstion_items_enveloping

        if overlapping_dimension_items_present:
            return 
        else:
            super(Dimension_Item, self).save(*args, **kwargs) # Call the "real" save() method.
```